# Receiving exception when trying to check if guess is empty or not

Tags: java

I have developed a hangman game which is 99% complete. I just have one glitch and the glitch is when the user does not enter in a guess and presses enter.

I know that we cannot check if a character is empty so instead I check if a string is empty using `scanner.nextLine().isEmpty()`. Now if I don't enter anything and I press enter then it works fine and outputs the printline message.

However if I enter in a letter and press enter, then it goes to the next line and it wants me to enter in something. If I enter in another letter then it works fine, if I enter in nothing and press enter then I get an exception where

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
```

So I believe my problem is the if statement where I check for string to be empty and if not then move onto checking the character:

```
            if (scanner.nextLine().isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("Your guess seems empty. Please enter in a letter or number");
            } else {

                char input = scanner.nextLine().charAt(0);

                if (input == '-' || Character.isLetter(input) || Character.isDigit(input)) {

                    if (input == '-') {
                        weArePlaying = false;
                        wordCompleted = true;
                    }
....
}
```

How can I jiggle this so that if empty string then ask user to guess again else if not empty then proceed with the guess?

Below is more of the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    ArrayList<String> movieList = new ArrayList<>();
    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\mmkp1\\Documents\\listofmovies.txt");
    Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(file);
    int attempts = 10;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random random = new Random();
    ArrayList<Character> guessedLetters = new ArrayList<>();

    while (fileScanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = fileScanner.nextLine();
        // Reads the whole file
        movieList.add(line);
    }

    boolean weArePlaying = true;
    while (weArePlaying) {
        System.out.println("Welcome to Guess The Movie Game");

        int index = random.nextInt(movieList.size());
        String getMovies = movieList.get(index);
        char[] randomWordToGuess = getMovies.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
        int wordLength = randomWordToGuess.length;
        char[] playerGuess = new char[wordLength];
        boolean wordCompleted = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < playerGuess.length; i++) {
            playerGuess[i] = '_';
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < randomWordToGuess.length; i++) {
            if (randomWordToGuess[i] == ' ') {
                playerGuess[i] = ' ';
            }
        }


        while (!wordCompleted && attempts != 0) {

            printArray(playerGuess);
            System.out.println("Number of attempts left: " + attempts);
            System.out.println("Your previous guesses were:" + guessedLetters);
            System.out.println("Enter a letter or number");

            if (scanner.nextLine().isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("Your guess seems empty. Please enter in a letter or number");
            } else {

                char input = scanner.nextLine().charAt(0);

                if (input == '-' || Character.isLetter(input) || Character.isDigit(input)) {

                    if (input == '-') {
                        weArePlaying = false;
                        wordCompleted = true;
                    }
....
}
```

Comment: You're actually calling `nextLine` twice. First in the `if`, then in the `else`

Comment: can you add full stacktrace of exception? EDIT: no need, @FedericoklezCulloca gaves the answer

Comment: You need to save the returned value to a variable. When you write `scanner.nextLine().isEmpty()` you are immediately using it then throwing the value away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the scanner wrong and calling `nextLine()` twice.

```
if (scanner.nextLine().isEmpty()) {            // First call.
    System.out.println("empy");
}
else {
    char input = scanner.nextLine().charAt(0); // Second call.
}
```

Let's say the scanner has an interesting line for us.
The *first call* will get it, see that it is not empty and throw it away.
The *second call* will not get our interesting line but will attempt to get a (possibly empty) following line.

Trying to access the first character of an empty string results in the `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` you posted.

You can easily fix your code with the help of a local variable like so:

```
String line;
char   input;

line = scanner.nextLine();
if (line.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println("empy");
    return;
}

input = line.charAt(0);
// ...
```

Comment: That worked, only thing I need to work out is not to end the game after I press enter as it displays the message and then the console seems to finish